# Search jira issues with open subtasks

Tags: jira, jql

We currently handle the progress of our tasks solely by using subtaks under each issue. For this reason, I would like to create a filter that only displays those issues that have at least one subtask that is stil open.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Script Runner` plugin (older versions are free) with this JQL:

```
issueFunction in parentsOf("issuetype in ('Sub-Task') and statusCategory != Complete")
```

You'll need to state all possible sub task types for issuetype.

Comment: so no way of doing it with basic JQL?

Comment: you could do (your sub task query) and parent in (...) but you'd have to name issue keys one by one

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work as a filter?

```
project=PROJECTNAME AND issueType in subTaskIssueTypes() AND status ="To Do (or Open or whatever you are using)"
```

This should pull all issues that are in the sub task group (Sub-task, Sub-bug, etc.), that are in your current project and that have the desired status (Either the one you are looking for, or you could switch it to exclude the statuses you do not need like "Done").

Comment: please add some explanations of your code to the answer, it will help the user who asked the question

Comment: Dang, responded to comment and no upvote love. Well, here you go!